# Icecast stream switching sources without the clients stopping playback

Tags: python, icecast, raspberry-pi4

Good morning :)

I have some questions regarding an icecast-setup.
We have my own (Nextcloud)-Server sitting in our church. This works perfectly fine and since here in Germany the community services got forbidden already once during all this Covid19-stuff, we want to have a stream-setup. I managed to set up an icecast-instance on our server and we use my old laptop with Rocket Broadcaster and a Steinberg CI2 to provide the source for the stream. That works all as intended. We already used it once because we stopped public services for two weeks after one of our member got tested positive after he went abroad for a week.
Our operator on the PA doesn't want to have another display there, which would disturb him from listening the sermon.

My project regarding this: I have a RPi4 and a Behringer U-Phoria UMC202HD. The input atm is a standard mic, that is connected to the Interface.
The Pi is configured with darkice and uses its own icecast installation, while I am testing everything at home. Since I started the streaming project, after the service we switched Rocket Broadcaster to use VLC and a folder of old service recordings (mastered and in MP3-format) to provide a source to listen while we are at work or on travels. This option gets used pretty regularly and I want to keep it going.
My plan is to have a little box with a LED levelmeter, where the input level is shown. That should be done with a little python script. Also I want to add two buttons, where presets for the two setups get loaded. Button 1: kill the current source and start the darkice livestream. Button 2: kill the current source and start the playback of old recordings. Both options should have visual feedback for the operator. The raspberry has to work in headless mode without need for a VNC or SSH-connection for the normal usage.

My problem: I tried:
`sudo killall darkice && /home/pi/darkice.sh`

This code will get changed, because I probably have to use ices for the mp3-playback. So basically it kills darkice, starts the ices playback (for now only restarts the stream in a blink) and vice versa.
The bash-file exists and gets executed at reboot via cronjob. That works well. When I execute the above mentioned killall command, icecast continues the broadcast almost instantly, but the stream stops on the clients. Everyone needs to restart it.
Do I have an option to change the setup, so that I am able to switch between the two options without the need for everyone to restart?
My plan was to create a bash-script, where I do this all inside and execute it via GPIO-input and pythoncode.

Thanks in advance!